# What can/should be in setup()'s return {}, and what must be directly in setup()?

Tags: vuejs3

I started with Vue3 some time ago (moving from Vue2) and I find the Composition API great (at least at my amateur/hobby dev level).

I got used to the structure

```
setup() {

    let a = ref(0)
    const standaloneFunction = () => 5;
    const functionUsingRefs = () => 10 * a.value

    return {
        a,
        standaloneFunction,
        functionusingRefs,
    }
}
```

To my surprise, I discovered today some code that would rather

```
setup() {

    return {
        a: ref(0),
        standaloneFunction() { return 5 },
        functionUsingRefs() { 10 * a.value },
    }
}
```

In other words, what is returned is defined on the spot. This leads to shorter and more readable code (which is certainly a matter of taste).

**My question**: taking `functionUsingRefs()` in the example above, can I always assume that a reactive variable, decalred either right under `setup()` or in its `return {}` will be available in `return {}`?

Or said differently: are there elements (refs, functions, ...) that **must** be declared right in `setup()` to be available for other elements (specifically to the ones in `return {}`)?

Comment: that is also a valid syntax as of any function. Primary difference between `setup` and options API's data, computed is, in setup you can create internal variable or function which does not exposes to template; but in options everything in data, computed, methods are available to template. Note: this is not the entire difference in them, read the documentation for further details

Comment: there is also a step 3 with [vue 3.2](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3.2.html) -> write `<script setup>` ... function functionUsingRefs() {} .... </script> - voilá. You'll save the indentation.

Comment: @wittgenstein: ah, this is neat - I did not know that (and the style bind on the same page). Thanks!